# Does Microsoft Office run in Crossover/Wine/Playonlinux?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office, crossover

I'm a student so I kinda need full compatibility with Microsoft Office Documents for school.  I was wondering if Office will run without major problems in Crossover, Wine, or playonlinux?

Comment: Do you need a specific MSOffice version? Do you need it to read files, to edit them or to co-work documents?

Comment: Probably 2010 or 2013

Comment: this question is a partial duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/q/155809/47206

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is **yes**. In fact the other two are also based on Wine.

Considering just **Wine**, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/155809/47206). But later versions of MSOffice, 2007 and 2010, are much easier to install in Wine than older versions like 2003 and XP. For 2007 and later see my other [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/258347/47206). (Personally, I was not able to install msoffice xp or 2003 in Wine, although I deem it possible.).

**Playonlinux** has the advantage of offering the possibility of using different versions of Wine for different programs or program versions. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/258717/47206) answer for more details on installing msoffice 2007.

**CrossOver** greatly facilitates the installation of MSOffice, even of different versions that could be used in parallel, new and old. (I was able to install very easily msofficexp.) This is a very useful and recommendable application, especially for the users who want the comfort and are ready to pay for it.

(To make things even smoother, you can improve appearance of the programs installed in this way; for Wine and playonlinux, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/219795/47206); for crossover, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/271210/47206).)

Related answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/271295/47206).

Answer (score 1):

2007 would probably work under wine. It has .docx support, and that is the main codec you would be worried about. 2010 might work, but I wouldn't push my luck. Wine can be frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what version of wine and Office you are trying to use.  The wine app database is a great resource for finding information on what runs well in wine and what doesn't. According to the [Office Installer db entry](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=31), the installers for 2000 through 2007 work reasonably well and the 32 bit version of 2010.  Anything after that runs like "garbage" in wine. After checking the installer there are different entries for each of the different components of Office.

[Word](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10) - [Excel](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11) - [PowerPoint](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13) - [Access](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=12) - [FrontPage](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=15) - [Outlook](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=34) - [OneNote](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2911) - [Publisher](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=663) - [Project](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6543) - [Visio](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=119) - [Schedule+](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3914) - [Groove](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9126)

One thing to note about these entries is that they are based on subjective reviews. That being said, they are the best resource for this sort of thing and I usually find them to be pretty accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will run. The only problem you will face is that when office is installed this way, it will be installed for one user only.

You can copy or use links to the wine folder, but you have to edit all the wine/playonlinux... config files manually, because the user name is hardcoded in the paths. (I simply changed it to $user)

Office 2003 works like charm, 2007 has some problems (copy-paste for eg.), 2010 needs to much extra, but it will run also on the newest wine.

Answer (score 0):

MS Office 2010 mostly works on Crossover, but some limitations may apply as a marketing small print paragraph would say. iE : No multiple parameter search working in Outlook, no import of whatever source in Access.. It is a bit of a lottery when it comes to what is working and what isn't..